# supress confidence interval footnote in tbl_regression

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am using tbl_regression from the gtsummary package.
When generating an output table from linear regression there is a **1CI = Confidence Interval** footnote appearing in the bottom row.

Is there a way to supress this footnote in tbl_regression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA, abbreviation = TRUE)` to delete abbrev. footnotes

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

my_table <-
  lm(mpg ~ disp, mtcars) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = FALSE) %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA, abbreviation = TRUE)
my_table
```

[image]

Comment: This same approach does not seem to work with a tbl_summary that has a difference column generated with add_difference(). The CI note remains, and I can seem to get rid of it.

Comment: @MikeS Try this: `mtcars %>%
  tbl_summary(by = am) %>%
  add_difference() %>% 
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA, abbreviation = TRUE)` This will remove CI footnote after `add_difference()`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @TarJae. I had already tried that, but it does NOT actually work (did you try it yourself)? It seems like it should, but it leaves behind "2 Welch Two Sample t-test; Standardized Mean Difference; Two sample test for equality of proportions"