# Supress table header in tbl_regression of gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

**Update** to clarify and show intention:

The related question is here [tbl_merge: sort variables alphabetically in merged tbl_regression models {gtsummary}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70409367/tbl-merge-sort-variables-alphabetically-in-merged-tbl-regression-models-gtsumm) and @Daniel D. Sjoberg already provided the correct and professional answer.

But I want to try if this is possible:

```
x <- tbl_merge(list(t1, t2, t3 ,t4))

y <- x %>% 
  tbl_split(variables = c(age, ttdeath, response, death, stage, grade))
```

With this code I split the table into one row tables:

`y[[1]]`

[image]

`y[[2]]`

[image]

**and so on.....**

**Now:** I want to remove each footnote and header and merge them in a defined order together.
In essence it is the reversal of spliting?!

Thanks for your time and energy!

**First question:**

With the `tbl_regression()` function from `gtsummary` we can make a table.

By adding `modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA, abbreviation = TRUE)` we can omit footnotes.

like here: from:[supress confidence interval footnote in tbl_regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266491/supress-confidence-interval-footnote-in-tbl-regression/70266681#70266681)

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

my_table <-
  lm(mpg ~ disp, mtcars) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = FALSE) %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA, abbreviation = TRUE)
my_table
```

Result:

[image]

**My question:**

How can I remove the header part of this table to get this output:

[image]

If possible it should be possible with `modify_header` or `modify_table_styling()`?!

There is a rationale behind.

The ultimate goal is to split each element of a gtsummary table [Split long gtsummary() table to n smaller tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119997/split-long-gtsummary-table-to-n-smaller-tables) and rearrange them in a given order [tbl_merge: sort variables alphabetically in merged tbl_regression models {gtsummary}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70409367/tbl-merge-sort-variables-alphabetically-in-merged-tbl-regression-models-gtsumm)

Comment: There is no way to remove a header from a gtusmmary table with a gtsummary function. You can convert the gtsummary table to a gt object with `as_gt()`, and use `gt::tab_options(column_labels.hidden=)` to hide the column labels/headers. But then you can't combine the individual tables back together.

If you update the post with an example of what you'd like in the end, perhaps I can guide you more on how to get what you're after?

Comment: Thank you. Please see my update. But do not take to much time with it. It was just an idea!

Comment: Once you've split your table, you can re-assemble it with `tbl_stack()`. No need to worry about the headers and footnotes...they will work themselves out. `tbl_stack(list(y[[2)]], y[[1)]])`

Comment: Oh that is wonderful. Please share this as answer it is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've split your table, you can re-assemble it with `tbl_stack()`. No need to worry about the headers and footnotes...they will work themselves out. `tbl_stack(list(y[[2)]], y[[1)]])`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach using the `huxtable` backend:

```r
ht <- as_hux_table(my_table)
ht <- ht[2,] # just row 2

# and to bind multiple huxtables together, do e.g.
rbind(ht, ht2, ht3)
```

After this you can edit the style appropriately using huxtable functions.

Comment: That is wonderful an new for me. Thank you a lot. Do you know if it is possible to get something similiar to gt_summary table.

Comment: That is a gtsummary table. gtsummary uses huxtable (or gt, or other packages) as a backend. If you want the header rows, then just take `ht[1,]` and `rbind` it to the top.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you for sharing!